# Android icon on action-bar

Tags: java, android, xml

My code :

**In java file**

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main , menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**In menu xml file**

```
  <menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.patryk.menu_test.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/group_item1"
    android:title="settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/group_item2"
    android:title="about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

**onCreate**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**My problem:** I don't see any icons on my actionBar.

- Do you have any idea why?
- Any advice about standard mistakes in this subject?

PS. I'm using android studio.

thanks .

Comment: Why you added 2 code blocks as answers? If you want to add something to your question, just edit it - I suggest you do that and then remove these "answers"

Comment: sorry i am not experienced on stackoverflow , but now i hope that is better

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the icon that each menu item will use. This can be done with:

`android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a `drawable`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/group_item1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawable_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|Always" />
```

here `ic_drawable_settings` is a drawable. Also you need following two `override` methods

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.YOUR_MENU_ID) {
        //.....your code here 
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: when i did this my action bar is still empty

Comment: you should post more code for our evaluation. you might miss something else, did you set `actionbar` in `OnCreate`

Comment: my onCreate made android studio so i hope that is okej